# How do I add a loop to go through folders to this code?

Tags: excel, vba

by looking at other people's code and modifying it, I managed to piece together this piece of code:

```
Sub LookForNew()
Dim n As String, msg As String, d As Date
msg = ""
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set fils = fso.GetFolder(Range("B4")).Files
For Each fil In fils
    n = fil.Name
    d = fil.DateCreated
    If d >= Range("E1") Then
        msg = msg & n & vbTab & d & vbCrLf
        Range("C4") = Range("B1")
    End If
Next fil
If msg = "" Then
    MsgBox "No new files"
    Range("C4") = Range("B1")
Else
    MsgBox msg
End If
Set fso = Nothing
End Sub
```

This loops through the files in the folder (Path is in "B4"). If there are filers newer than the date given in "E1", it returns an alert.

What I would like to add to this is a loop that loops through all the folder paths given in the range "B4:B22" and repeats the above actions for each file in these folders. So far I have only run into errors...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I have understood your question correctly, I would simply wrap the required actions in a `Do Until` where the row is incremented by 1 in each iteration.

Obviously if the Range "B4:B22" changes then this could be made smarter.

```
Private Sub LookForNew()  
Dim n As String, msg As String, d As Date
msg = ""
rownum = 3
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

Do Until rownum = 24
rownum = rownum + 1
Set fils = fso.GetFolder(Range("B" & rownum)).Files
    For Each fil In fils
        n = fil.Name
        d = fil.DateCreated
        If d >= Range("E1") Then
            msg = msg & n & vbTab & d & vbCrLf
            Range("C4") = Range("B1")
        End If
    Next fil

    If msg = "" Then
        MsgBox "No new files"
        Range("C4") = Range("B1")
    Else
        MsgBox (msg)
    End If

    'Set fso = Nothing
Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This worked well and is pretty quick!